# Dplyr mutate with group_by gives me incorrect values (BUG?)

Tags: r, dplyr

Please see reproducible example below. The first example returns the incorrect vector for the OUT variable (the OUT value for group 2 should be 10).

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c(1, 1,2,2)
v <- c(NA,NA,10,20)
t <- c(1,2,1,2)
df = data.frame(x,v,t)
df = df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(out=v[which.min(t)])
df$out
```

The example below only changes one value for group 1, but this causes the command to return the correct answer for group 2 (the other group).

```
 v <- c(1,NA,10,20)
 df = data.frame(x,v,t)
 df = df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(out=v[which.min(t)])
 df$out
```

Am I missing something or is this a computing error?

Comment: Looks like a bug indeed. I'm getting the correct result using `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, out := v[which.min(t)], by = x]`. Try this on the latest version of `dplyr` (the development one on GH), and if it is still not working, report as a bug on GH.

Comment: For the first group, we have `which.min(c(NA, NA))` which returns `integer(0)`. I guess this is where the problem comes from.

Comment: @coffeinjunky the are no `NA`s in `t` in neither of the groups of `x` so how is it even related here? This is also works fine in base R `with(df, ave(t, x, FUN = which.min))`. Btw,

Comment: @David I don't know but as far as I know `dplyr` can't handle the case that the outcome vectors are of different length. I am just guessing though.

Comment: @coffeinjunky but it neither of the groups a situation `which.min(c(NA, NA))` doesn't happen-  there are no `NA`s in `t` **at all**

Comment: Am I missing something? Both work fine for me.

Comment: @David: ha, you are right! I was looking at `v` and noted that the difference is that all values of `v` are missing values in the first example. I overlooked that the subsetting is based on `t`. Thanks for pointing it out. I am still guessing whatever causes this behavior is related to this, though I agree it should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved in the current development version, `dplyr_0.4.3.9001`.

**To solve the problem you have to do the following (from [issue #1904](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1904#issuecomment-225236529%22issue%20#1904%22) on GitHub):**

```
# 1. Install current dev. version of 'devtools'

         devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools")

# 2. Restart R session  - IMPORTANT!

# 3. After restart install dev. version of both 'lazyeval' and 'dplyr'  

        devtools::install_github("hadley/lazyeval")
        devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```

Comment: Did you find this helpful?